# Resolve Compilation Errors of Simulink C-Code in matlab function: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token

Tags: c, matlab, code-generation, simulink

Following up the Matlab/Simulink tutorial at https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/incorporate-c-code-using-a-matlab-function-block.html

A basic c-code shall be put into a matlab function block. Compiling the Simulink model leads to the following error message:

> C:\Users...\Matlab\slprj_slcc\6BPyb7AdG47rnTRBAilVFG\customcode_6BPyb7AdG47rnTRBAilVFG.c:4:9:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '.'
>   token  doubleIt.c
>            ^

I am using the MinGW Compiler with Matlab/Simulink. Bit puzzled of where to look for error-fixing, as it SEEMS to be exactly the tutorial written down.

Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: I've seen errors like that before when the header file wasn't specified, or incorrectly specified.  First thing I'd suggest is to check that you've done all header steps in the linked tutorial correctly.

Comment: The header was copy/pasted like in the tutorial and later specified in Simulink's Configuration Parameters as Header file: #include "doubleIt.h" and Source files: doubleIt.c

Comment: Ok, the error is fixed. As in the Configuration Parameters Dialogue header- and source file were specified, but at wrong places due to trial-and-error. So the header file was inserted wrongly at the "Insert custom C code in generated: Source File" position. Thus giving Simulink wrong inputs for header and source file.

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, please, write it as an answer and mark it. This way later visitors see that your problem is solved and **1.** find an answer for their similar problem, or **2.** don't waste time reading all comments finding that you don't need any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Simulink's Configuration Parameters Dialogue, the header- and source file was specified at the wrong input-registers (due to trial-and-error). The header file was inserted mistakenly at the "Insert custom C code in generated: Source File" position. Thus giving Simulink incorrect inputs for header and source file.